# How can I visualize a list of numbers?

Tags: r, plot

I have a list of numbers as:

```
vector = c(0.1, 0.25, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15)
```

I want to visualize this list as following. I want to draw a rectangular box with 8 inner small square boxes each filled withe a color with RGB value associated with the related numerical value in the list. For example, R = 0, G = 0, and B = value_from_list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(ggplot2)
myVector <- c(0.1, 0.25, 0.1, 0.05, 0.05, 0.15, 0.15, 0.15)
ggplot(data.frame(x = 1:8, y = 0), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_tile(fill = rgb(0, 0, myVector)) + 
  coord_fixed() + 
  theme_void()
```